# Authentication mechanisms for a AngularJS/NodeJS/RESTEasy+JBoss/LDAP stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, angularjs, jboss

I'm looking for some authentication/security mechanisms or best practices on an application stack set up like this:

- AngularJS front-end
- NodeJS web server
- RESTEasy backend running on JBoss AS 7
- LDAP authentication

If possible, I'd like Angular to present the login dialog so it's pretty and not the standard browser HTTP authentication dialog, but that's more of a preference than a requirement. I have a pretty good feel (based on [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/tree/master/client/src/common/security)) of how that could work.

I've already got the RESTEasy service set up to require LDAP authentication on JBoss so that a user can't simply hit the REST endpoints without authentication; I've used EE6 realms/roles for that part but I'm open to whatever works best.

Where I'm a bit stuck is the middle layer. Is there a way to use the same credentials to authenticate with both JBoss (to provide data) and NodeJS (so the app knows who the user is)?

I imagine the answer depends on whether the app uses CORS, and I'm fine with whatever makes sense there.

Edit: OAuth or other third-party authentication types aren't attractive, as this is purely an internal application.

Thanks!

Comment: May I know what's the place of Node if you already have a REST backend? Who talks to the LDAP server?

Comment: Node (with express) simply serves up the AngularJS site.

Comment: Right now JBoss is hitting LDAP in order to secure the REST API; Node may or may not also have to hit LDAP to secure the UI (part of my question, I suppose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of a non-answer here but I'll describe how I got around my issue: I took Node out of the stack altogether. Both the API and web app are now hosted directly by JBoss. The HTTP Basic/LDAP auth done by JBoss takes care of my authentication. Since they're on the same machine, protocol, etc, CORS isn't required so I've sidestepped that issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to use HTTP Basic/Digest authentication you can use [http-auth](https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth) module for that.

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Creating new HTTP server.
http.createServer(basic, function(req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
}).listen(1337);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can generate an auth token for a given section in JBoss, the token is:

- put in a data store accessible to the node server (could be MongoDB, CouchDB, you name it)
- stored in client's cookie to the node server

The node server can then use the token to cross verify if the client has been properly authenticated and protects pages (other then the login page).

Comment: That would definitely work. In this case I want to stick with HTTP basic authentication (tokenless) so it's not the approach I'm taking.